# What happens to the malloc'ed memory when exit(1) is encountered?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free, exit

In C, if I allocate a memory using `malloc` and during the execution, the program encounters an exception/error and exits with a manually incorporated `exit(1)` statement in the program, does C compiler automatically frees the memory before making the unexpected exit or do I have to manually do this just before the `exit(1)` line in the program.

I use the gcc-4.5.2 compiler on Ubuntu 32bit platform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you call `exit`, OS takes all the allocated memory back. So no need to call `free`.

Edit:
But It's generally good practice to free memory you allocated in your program as you may overlook it the call to free when you modify it in the future.

Comment: No need to call `free()` is a fundamentally bad advice.And should definitely not be encouraged.

Comment: @Als Question is: `do I have to manually do this just before the exit...` So calling `free` just before calling `exit` is certainly unnecessary here.

Comment: The answer should reflect good programming practices instead of encouraging bad practices,it might create false impressions in the mind of the OP or someone new to the language who doesn't really know and just goes by the *advice*, So the advice better be complete.Reading this answer someone might draw an conclusion that they don't even need to free other resources on program exit which is definitely not true.You should understand the implications of your answer when making a statement like that and unless you update your answer to reflect that, You have my -1.

Comment: @Als I edited it to reflect your point. However, I expect any future reader who reads my answer also reads the context of the question.

Comment: @Als: I disagree. Calling `free` recursively on structures that might not have been touched for days or weeks right before you `exit` is extremely harmful. It thrashes swap, evicts tons of actually-useful data/cache from physical ram, and accomplishes *nothing* except making valgrind happy. Why do you think Firefox takes 20+ seconds to go away after you click the close button?

Comment: @R..: I don't know what you disagree to, *Best Practices*? I think I have made my objection quite clear in the comment.I don't have anything more to say.

Comment: This is "best practices" in the same way avoiding goto is "best practices" - an inflexible and over-simplified rule that doesn't solve the core problem. The properly-stated rule should be "minimize the lifetime of dynamically allocated memory". In this form, note that calling `free` just before `exit` makes no difference to the lifetime. Further, if for example you allocated a block of memory at startup and never used it again, calling `free` on it just before `exit` does not solve the problem. Instead you should call `free` as soon as you're done with it.

Comment: @R..: An good answer should point out the subtle detail with an explanation.Just saying it is not necessary to `free` memory before `exit` is misleading to someone starting to learn the language.An answer be complete or not make bold statements which only make people more confused and misled than they already are.

Comment: I think the answer would be better if it pointed out these subtleties, yes.

Answer (score 6):

On a well-designed operating system, when a process exits (either using exit(), die(), abort() or raise() or by being killed by an error, a signal or whatever else), the operating system should free up all the resources used by the process, including stack space, heap, the allocated memory (usually on the heap), close the open file descriptors (if it's a *NIX system) etc.

However, I won't go for 'No need to call free()'. It's a bad programming/design concept if you don't explicitly free() memory that you have malloc()'ed and although you eventually can rely on the OS to do this for you, it may cause memory leaks when you later modify your project not to exit but you forget to free() your used memory.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking it is 'unnecessary'. But who knows. I even feel bad when I do it. :D